Login exception with Firebase
I have a problem in login into firebase / I wrote the following method:
private void loginUser(String txtLogemail, String txtLogPw) {
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(txtLogemail,txtLogPw).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
            Toast.makeText(login.this,"login suucsessfuly",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(login.this,MainActivity.class));
            //finish();
        }
    });
}

And i received the following exception:

Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=signInWithPassword)with exception - The supplied auth credential is incorrect, malformed or has expired.

The exactly same code-in another application is not giving me any exceptions and is working fine.
I don't understand why, thanks for any useful help.
This is the method I wrote:
private void loginUser(String txtLogemail, String txtLogPw) {
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(txtLogemail,txtLogPw).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
            Toast.makeText(login.this,"login suucsessfuly",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(login.this,MainActivity.class));
            //finish();
        }
    });
}

This is the exception I received:

Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=signInWithPassword)with exception - The supplied auth credential is incorrect, malformed or has expired.


Can you please show us, how you log the error? There is nothing in your code that indicates that,
